# How to Configure SSRS Web Service Port via Command Line

Tags: windows-server, ssrs-2014

It is straightforward to change the TCP port of SSRS using the GUI (Reporting Services Configuration Manager) but I am trying to fully script the installation and config of our SSRS servers.

Is it possible to change the TCP port of the SSRS web service via command line?

I have looked through [this SSRS documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/script-deployment-and-administrative-tasks?view=sql-server-2014), but don't see the option to change the TCP port.

**UPDATE:**
There is still no facility that I can find - as of SQL Server 2014 - to programmatically change the port of SSRS's web service. [As per Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/script-deployment-and-administrative-tasks?view=sql-server-2014), "You must write custom code that makes calls into the Report Server WMI provider. There are no command line utilities or script templates for configuring the URLs."

And even then, the port cannot be changed.

I tried editing the rsreportserver.config file and changing the port in there, but that resulted in "This page can’t be displayed" errors. Bah!